# Where did my Perl 6 operator go after I defined a more specific multi?

Tags: raku, multidispatch

I'm playing with this little thing where a set can act as its complement by flipping around the tests. In order to make that work, I create special versions of the membership operators.

```
class Complement {
    has $.set;
    }

multi infix:<∈> ( $a, Complement:D $c ) { $a ∉ $c.set   }
multi infix:<∉> ( $a, Complement:D $c ) { $a ∈ $c.set }

my $set = (1, 2, 3).Set;
my $c = Complement.new: set => $set;

put 3 ∈ $set;
put 4 ∈ $c;
```

With my definition of `infix:<∉>` the other, more general one seems to have disappeared. There are no other candidates:

```
True
Cannot resolve caller infix:<∉>(Int, Set); none of these signatures match:
    ($a, Complement:D $c)
  in sub infix:<∈> at /Users/brian/Desktop/complement.p6 line 11
  in block <unit> at /Users/brian/Desktop/complement.p6 line 18
```

What do I need to do to retain previous definitions with different signatures?

Comment: As of https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/16b57af549 this will now work, as `multi infix:<∉>` is now also a multi in core.

Answer (score 14):

This is because `&infix:<∈>` is a multi, while `&infix:<∉>` is not:

```
$ perl6 -e '&infix:<∈>.candidates.head.multi.say'
True
$ perl6 -e '&infix:<∉>.candidates.head.multi.say'
False
```

When you defined your `multi &infix:<∉>`, you shadowed `only &infix:<∉>` from core, and that's why you see only your candidate.

We can probably detect such a situation and require the user to provide explicit `proto` to clarify what they meant. I filed that as [R#1530](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1530). And I'd say such differences that one op is a `multi` while another is an `only` is part of a larger issue of having consistent core; I added it as a comment on [RT#130020](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=130020#txn-1532843) and mentioned the problem in our docs on [D#1783](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1783).

You could define your custom op like so (if the suggestion in `R#1530` is implemented, the `proto` would be required; currently it isn't):

```
proto infix:<∉> (|) {*}
multi infix:<∉> ($a, Complement:D $c) { $a ∈ $c.set }
multi infix:<∉> (|c) { &CORE::infix:<∉>(|c) }
```

---

I can only guess what you're trying to code, but thought I'd mention it, for you to account for it in your creation: negated ops are defined as `not A (op) B`, not `A (not(op)) B`. This small difference has impact when it comes to [`Junctions`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junctions):

```
$ perl6 -e 'say 2 ≠ 2|4'
False
```

If it were defined as a negated op applied to each operand, the above would be equivalent to (`2 ≠ 2 or 2 ≠ 4)` and would always be `True`, which is often not what the programmer would've meant, hence why it's instead computed as `not (2 == 2 or 2 == 4)`

---

To reply to Jarrod's comments on OP: subs (including grammar mutations done by declaring custom operators) are lexical, so if you wrapped the declaration into a `BEGIN` block, the custom op will be scoped to just that block.

And the reason it appeared to work in REPL is because there's actually a bug ([RT#131900](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131900)) where custom ops are lost between REPL lines, so just as with the `BEGIN` block, by the time the call came with args destined to the core candidates, the custom multi was no longer in scope.

Comment: Ah wow, my bad. I actually thought I explicitly tested to see that both custom ops were working. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @JarrodFunnell they work in a sense that there's no crash, but the candidate it goes through is the core one, so the output is "True/False" rather than the expected "True/True"